# Read specific text with bash and save to .txt

Tags: bash, shell

How can I read after `.` up to `__` and save in a new `.txt` file with bash?

File

```
 2021-01-12-1530.HUIG__002                                                 
 2021-01-12-1530.MEIG__002                                                 
 2021-01-12-1530.PCIG__002                                                 
 2021-01-12-1530.PEIG__002                                                 
 2021-01-12-1530.PNIG__002                                                 
 2021-01-12-1530.TGIG__002                                                 
 2021-01-12-1530.TOIG__002                                                 
 2021-01-12-1530.TPIG__002                                                 
 2021-01-12-1530.TXIG__002                                                 
 2021-01-12-1530.UXUV__002                                                 
 2021-01-12-1530.CCIG__002                                                 
 2021-01-12-1530.CMIG__002                                                 
 2021-01-12-1530.OXIG__002                                                 
 2021-01-12-1530.PLIG__002                                                 
 2021-01-12-1530.TUIG__002                                                 
 2021-01-12-1530.YAIG__002                                                 
 2021-01-12-1530.ZIIG__002                                                 
 2021-01-12-1530.FTIG__002                                                 
 2021-01-12-1530.NEUV__002                                                 
 2021-01-12-1530.TLIG__002                                                 
 2021-01-12-1530.YOIG__002                                                 
 2021-01-12-1530.DAIG__002                                                 
 2021-01-12-1530.HLIG__002
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
$ head file1.txt 
2021-01-12-1530.HUIG__002                                                 
2021-01-12-1530.MEIG__002                                                 
2021-01-12-1530.PCIG__002                                                 
2021-01-12-1530.PEIG__002                                                 
2021-01-12-1530.PNIG__002                                                 
2021-01-12-1530.TGIG__002                                                 
2021-01-12-1530.TOIG__002                                                 
2021-01-12-1530.TPIG__002                                                 
2021-01-12-1530.TXIG__002                                                 
2021-01-12-1530.UXUV__002
$ cut -d. -f2 file1.txt | cut -d_ -f1 | head
HUIG
MEIG
PCIG
PEIG
PNIG
TGIG
TOIG
TPIG
TXIG
UXUV
```

And saving to a new file:

```
cut -d. -f2 file1.txt | cut -d_ -f1 > file2.txt
```

Comment: "Thanks" -JuanR

Comment: You are welcome! If it helped, please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`(1)

```
sed 's/^.*\.//;s/__.*$//' file.txt > new_file.txt
```

With GNU `grep`(1) which has support for `PCRE`

```
grep -Po '(?<=\.).*(?=__.*)' file.txt > new_file.txt
```